# How to best describe a raging sea

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

What are the best adjectives describing a chaotic and uncalm sea? I mean, when there are horrifyingly tall waves.

Comment: Are you looking for poetic terms or do you want conventional nautical descriptions?

Comment: Sorry, there is no "best" adjective for anything. Words are subjective.

Comment: Try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_state)

Comment: Probably " a heavy sea".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stormy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stormy) :

> indicative of or characterized by storms; tempestuous:
>
> - *stormy seas.*

also, [turbulent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/turbulent)

> a characterized by turbulence; ***tempestuous:***
>
> - *turbulent waters.*

[Rough](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rough):

> Characterized by violent motion; turbulent:
>
> - *rough waters.*

The Free Dictionary

Comment: These are the "best" adjectives? Not "tempestuous" or "cruel" or "wave-tossed" or "foam-flecked" or "churning" or "roiling" or—well, you get the idea. My point is that the OP's question is misguided, as are attempts to answer it at face value.

Comment: @Robusto - I think OP is looking for help regarding adjectives that describe a "chaotic and uncalm" sea. Best? Best you can think of probably.

Comment: Also **heavy sea**

Comment: @Graffito - good one.

Comment: Rarer, but used in weather reports "confused sea".